# How to create a cronjob to backup crontab

Tags: cron

Is there a way I can set a cronjob to backup the crontab on a daily basis?

The current way I'm going about this is as follows:

```
00 12 * * * crontab -l > ~/Documents/crontab_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt
```

but it's not working at all. Issuing this in the terminal as a non-cronjob task works fine.

Comment: Try giving it the full path name to `crontab`: `00 12 * * * /bin/crontab -l ...`. The execution PATH shell variable isn't defined in a `cron` job unless you set it. So you can either set it yourself in the `cron` script, or use explicit paths.

Comment: How would I go about finding the explicit path to it?

Comment: `whereis crontab`. But it's likely where I indicated: `/bin/crontab`.

Comment: Thanks yeah it was there!